# tar archives error

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I need to search for a pattern (string) in all .tar archives and then append the names of archives which contains the pattern (string) provided in a text.txt folder. My code is:

```
for f in *.tar.gz 
do
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then
    found=$(tar -xvzf "$f" -O | grep -sE "$1")
    if [ ! -z "$found" ]; then
      echo "$f" >> text.txt
    fi
  fi

done
```

The problem is that I keep getting:

```
gzip:stdin:not in gzip format
tar:Child returned status 1
tar:Error is not recoverable:Exiting now
```

Comment: Your output indicates a data problem: `not in gzip format`.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in a file type. A file is not gz archive, but you tried to untar it `tar -xvzf "$f"`. In your case, possible, it is tar, but with tar.gz extension. 
Try to check type of files `file your_file.tar.gz` 
Or try it for all tar.gz files

```
for f in *.tar.gz 
do
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then
    file "$f"
  fi
done
```

Result for gz archive should be `my_file.tar.gz: gzip compressed data,...` 
If your files are tar archives, change `tar -xvzf ...` to `tar -xvf ...` in the script.

Comment: I have only one tar archive on my current directory.I used your command and i get: pac.tar.gz :POSIX tar archive (GNU)

Comment: @NistorMihnea, that means your file is tar, but not gz. In that case, you should change line 4 in your script. Instead "tar -xvzf", there should be "tar -xvf". Or, you can rename it to pac.tar (mv pac.tar.gz pac.tar), and make real gz by "gzip pac.tar". In that case, you do not need to change your script

Comment: Got it.The way i create tar archive is tar -cvf name.tar f1 f2 (f1 and f2 are folders).After i create this tar i should do gzip name.tar in order to use my script.If not i should use only tar -xvf right?

Comment: True. Also, you can create a tar.gz archive in one step "tar -czvf file1 file2 file3 pac.tar.gz"

Comment: Understood.Thanks a lot,